# RSpec refactoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm new to Ruby, Rails and RSpec, so I'm doing the [railstutorial](http://railstutorial.org/). In Chapter 10, exercise 1, I've implemented a test for micropost pluralization that I'm trying to refactor.

My first try was:

```
  describe "micropost pluralization" do
    let(:new_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in new_user
      visit root_path
    end
    
    describe "with no microposts" do
      it "should have no microposts" do
        expect(page).to have_text("0 microposts")
      end
    end
    
    describe "with one micropost" do
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Lorem ipsum")
        visit root_path
      end

      it "should have one micropost" do
        expect(page).to have_text("1 micropost")
      end
    end

    describe "with two microposts" do
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Lorem ipsum")
        FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Dolor sit amet")
        visit root_path
      end

      it "should have two microposts" do
        expect(page).to have_text("2 microposts")
      end
    end
  end
```

This clearly violates the DRY principle. As this test case describes a sequence, I tried to refactor by nesting:

```
  describe "micropost pluralization" do
    let(:new_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      sign_in new_user
      visit root_path
    end
    
    it "should have no microposts" do
      expect(page).to have_text("0 microposts")
    end
    
    describe "when one micropost is created" do
      before do
        FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Lorem ipsum")
        visit root_path
      end

      it "should have one micropost" do
        expect(page).to have_text("1 micropost")
      end
      
      describe "and then another micropost is created" do
        before do
          FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Dolor sit amet")
          visit root_path
        end
        it "should have two microposts" do
          expect(page).to have_text("2 microposts")
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

But I'm still repeating the "visit root_path" line, and that nesting looks ugly.
My questions are:

1 - Is there a better way than nesting to describe a sequence in RSpec? I tried mixing the creation of microposts and the assertions and didn't work.

2 - How could I remove the "visit root_path" duplication?

Thanks for reading this far!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [`shared_example_groups`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/example-groups/shared-example-group):

```
shared_examples_for 'page with n microposts' do |number_of_posts, expected_text|

  before do
    number_of_posts.times do
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: "Lorem ipsum")
    end
    visit root_path
  end

   it "should have correct text" do
     expect(page).to have_text(expected_text)
   end
end

it_should_behave_like 'page with n microposts', 0, '0 microposts'
it_should_behave_like 'page with n microposts', 1, '1 micropost'
it_should_behave_like 'page with n microposts', 2, '2 microposts'
```

Comment: That looks great! Didn't know about `shared_example_groups`.

Comment: I've tested it and works great, but there's still a subtlety: if the page doesn't pluralize correctly and always says "N microposts", the case "1 micropost" would still pass ("1 micropost" is included in "1 microposts"). How would you solve that?

Comment: how about changing it regex? `/1 micropost\b/` instead of `'1 micropost'`?

Answer (score 2):

I would personally make just a helper method to extract my logic for creation of objects.Here is the code and a better solution would be to pull `create_microposts` in a helper module to be included in your tests.I use `context` which describe clearly my expectations and that those are just similar tests, connected to each other.

```
describe "micropost pluralization" do
  def create_microposts(microposts)
    microposts.each do |micropost|
      FactoryGirl.create(:micropost, user: new_user, content: micropost)
    end
  end

  let(:new_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
  before do
    sign_in new_user
    create_microposts microposts
    visit root_path
  end

  context "when no microposts exist for user" do
    let(:microposts) { [] }
    it { is_expected.to have_text("0 microposts") }
  end

  context "when one micropost is created" do
    let(:microposts) { ["Lorem ipsum"] }
    it { is_expected.to have_text("1 microposts") }
  end

  context "when two micropost are created" do
    let(:microposts) { ["Lorem ipsum", "Dolor sit amet"] }
    it { is_expected.to have_text("2 microposts") }
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid nesting to describe sequences in RSpec you might want to check out [contexts](http://betterspecs.org/#contexts). As was pointed out in the comment to my answer, you cannot remove the duplicity of the `visit_root_path` due to the fact that the various test cases need different prerequisites (i.e. one needs 1 post to be created, the other needs 2).

I'd write this test suite like so:

```
describe 'micropost pluralization' do
  let :new_user { create :user } 
  before :all do
    sign_in new_user
  end

  context 'no microposts' do
    it 'should have no microposts' do
      visit_root_path
      expect(page).to have_text('0 microposts')
    end
  end 

  context 'one or more microposts' do
    # you could have a before :each here do create the posts, but
    # since you only have two test cases I don't feel it's necessary.

    it 'should have one micropost' do
      create :micropost, user: new_user, content: 'Lorem ipsum'
      visit_root_path
      expect(page).to have_text('1 micropost')
    end  

    it 'should have two microposts' do
      2.times.do { create :micropost, user: new_user, content: 'Lorem ipsum' }
      visit_root_path
      expect(page).to have_text('2 microposts')
    end
  end # end context

end # end describe
```

It might not look perfectly DRY, but it certainly looks readable to me.

I cannot recommend [betterspecs](http://betterspecs.org/) enough for test writing by the way :-)

Comment: That might not bring the right results.You are visiting the page first and then creating the posts, which will not render them on the page.